# Can't use session variables in integration test in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an issue using my session stored `return_to` URL in my integration tests.

Because my controller can be accesses from different places I store the referer in the session on the *new* action and redirect to it in my *create* action.

```
cards_controller.rb:
class CardsController < ApplicationController
...
  def new
    @card = current_user.cards.build
    session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
  end

  def create
    @card = current_user.cards.build(card_params)
    if @card.save
      flash[:success] = 'Card created!'
      redirect_to session.delete(:return_to) || root_path
    else
      render 'new', layout: 'card_new'
    end
  end
...
end
```

As I only use the create action in my test I would like to set the session variable in the integration test as I do in my unit test but it doesn't work. I always get redirected to the root path.

```
cards_interface_test.rb:
class CardsInterfaceTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'cards interface should redirect after successful save' do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get cards_path
    assert_select 'a[aria-label=?]', 'new'
    name = "heroblade"
    session[:return_to] = cards_url
    assert_difference 'Card.count', 1 do
      post cards_path, card: { name: name, icon: 'white-book', color: 'indigo', contents: 'subtitle | Rogue feature'}
    end
    assert_redirected_to cards_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_match name, response.body
    assert_select 'td', text: name
  end
end
```

The test fails on the `assert_redirected_to` line.

I tried to call `get new_card_path` first but made no difference and now I'm a little bit lost. I don't know if this should basically work but I made a tiny mistake or if I try to do something completely against best practices and should refactor all my interface tests to use something like Selenium or similar tools.

I tried as well to provide the session variable as part of the request like the rails guide describes for functional tests with no effects:

```
post cards_path, {card: { name: name, icon: 'white-book', color: 'indigo', contents: 'subtitle | Rogue feature' }}, {'return_to' => cards_url}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if manually setting session is possible in integration tests (guess rather not) but **you should be able to set the referer** because it's just a normal HTTP header. Headers can be passed as the [3rd parameter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L12) to the request method helper (`get` etc.) in integration tests.

So, I think you should first call the `new` action with the referer header set (so that it gets into the session) and then the `create` action should work including the redirect.

```
class CardsInterfaceTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'cards interface should redirect after successful save' do
    log_in_as(@user)

    # visit the 'new' action as if we came from the index page
    get new_card_path, nil, referer: cards_url

    assert_difference 'Card.count', 1 do
      post cards_path, card: { name: name, icon: 'white-book', color: 'indigo', contents: 'subtitle | Rogue feature'}
    end
    assert_redirected_to cards_url
    # ...
  end
end
```

First we try get the `new` action with the referer set as if we came from the index page (so that the referer can get into the `session`). The rest of the test stays the same.

Comment: Worked, thx. Didn't think about that I had to set the referer explicitly.